# Is it possible for an object to access private field / function of another object of same class?

Tags: f#

I know this is possible in C#, which produces simple and efficient code. ---  Two objects of the same class can access each other's private parts.

```
class c1
{
    private int A;

    public void test(c1 c)
    {
        c.A = 5;
    }
}
```

But It seems impossible in F#, is it true?

```
type c1()
     let A = 0
     member test (c: c1) = c.A
```

Comment: Your definition of `c1` has some syntax errors and doesn't compile, invalid attempt at accessing `c.A` aside.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting question. It seems to work with an explicit field but not with a let binding:

```
// Works
type c1 =
    val private A : int
    new(a) = { A = a }
    member m.test(c : c1) = c.A

let someC1 = new c1(1)
let someMoreC1 = new c1(42);
let theAnswer = someC1.test someMoreC1

// Doesn't work
type c2() =
    let mutable A = 42
    // Compiler error: The field, constructor or member 'A' is not defined
    member m.test(c : c2) = c.A
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but in your example `A` is not semantically a private member of `c1`, it is more like a local variable of the constructor.

@afrischke gives an example of how to define `c1` with an actual private member `A` (using `val` fields).

Comment: No, A is not a local constructor value. In fact, it is a private member, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483470.

Comment: @JohnReynolds - I said it was "more like" a local constructor value, not that it "is" one. "In fact, it is a private member": MSDN is misleading here, it *is* compiled to a private field, but that's an implementation detail. Semantically it is not compatible with CLI definition of private accessibility (see http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf, section I.8.5.3.2)

Comment: Of course, one can have different views of what "more like a local variable of the constructor" means. The way I interpreted that, is that `A` is only accessible inside the constructor. That's not the case here, since `A` is accessible to all member functions of the same instance of `c1` (though not to other instances of `c1`).

Answer (score 1):

You just use `a` directly in an instance method

```
type c1()
     let A = 0
     member x.test = A
```

For a static method this doesn't work as let bindings are slightly different - then you need a class definition like

```
type c1()
     private member x.A = 0
     static member test (A:c1) = A.A
```

Comment: Problem in 2nd example: you can't access members from a static method.

Answer (score 1):

As section [8.6.1](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc321997164).3 of the F# spec states:

> The functions and values defined by instance definitions are lexically scoped (and thus implicitly private) to the object being defined.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible and it is widely used, for example, for checking memberwise equality:

```
type c1 =
    member private this.A = 0
    interface IEquatable<c1> with
        member this.Equals (that: c1) = this.A = that.A
    // of course, it can be done in a regular method as well
    member this.Equals (that: c1) = this.A = that.A
```

Comment: This is a workaround, but here `A` is a property, not a field.

Comment: @Daniel There is no evidence if the OP needs fields. :) `let A = 0` may be just an error. Also @afrischke's answer seems to be sufficient for explicit fields.

Comment: The title asks if it's possible to access private fields. His C# example also uses fields.